# C# Windows Form - Apply filter to image normally but got NullReferenceException using Thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, filtering, nullreferenceexception

I'm applying a filter to multiple images, and it works well but really slow.

(NOTE: images, filter, filter_size, div are already loaded and assigned)

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    out[i] = MyFiltering((Bitmap)images[i], filter, filter_size, div);
```

Therefore, I tried to use a Thread for each image filtering to speed up as below:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    FilterThread[i] = new Thread(() => {out[i] = MyFiltering((Bitmap)images[i], filter, filter_size, div)}
    FilterThread[i].IsBackground = true;
    FilterThread[i].Start();
}
```

I've tried different ways *(e.g., ThreadPool, Task.Factory.StartNew)*, but always get the NullReferenceException in MyFiltering for input img (i.e., images[i]), which should be definitely NOT NULL!

Anyone has an idea?

Comment: What type is `images`?

Comment: `i` is being captured by the lambda, so it's advanced to an uninitialized element, which is now referenced by that thread instead of the one intended. See the [answer by J. Steen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45053492/5394572) using `iCopy`.

Comment: Another approaches are using Parallel.For https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-a-simple-parallel-for-loop or Select https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.parallelenumerable.select

Comment: Thanks to all of you. I tried iCopy method but failed, maybe I used in a wrong way, and then Parallel.For succeed! Thanks a lot!